# Decrypting with AES GCM on C#

Tags: python, c#

I'm trying to convert a python script to C#.
The python script can be found here: https://0bin.net/paste/2Gh1CZMvClGWDuCg#C1ZCL6oVy8o1UD6deTD32HYhrPrxhA65xs0eba3zADU

I'm currently working on the decrypting function, that does:

```
def decrypt_build_manifest(data: (bytes, bytearray)) -> str:
    size = len(data)
    with BytesIO(data) as bio:
        gcm_nonce = bio.read(0xC)
        bm_data_enc = bio.read(size - 0xC - 0x50)
        gcm_tag = bio.read(0x10)
        ed25519_sig = bio.read(0x40)

    try:
        cipher = AES.new(BUILD_MANIFEST_AES_KEY_STEAM, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=gcm_nonce, mac_len=0x10)
        cipher.update(b"build-manifest")
        bm_data_dec = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(bm_data_enc, gcm_tag)
    except:
        cipher = AES.new(BUILD_MANIFEST_AES_KEY_BNET, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=gcm_nonce, mac_len=0x10)
        cipher.update(b"build-manifest")
        bm_data_dec = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(bm_data_enc, gcm_tag)

    return bm_data_dec.decode("UTF8")
```

I can't find a good way to replicate this on C#. There is an AES GCM class documented by Microsoft, but it doesn't seem like it can do what I want. I also found a library called BouncyCastle which seems like could help, however I can't find any good documentation on how to use it. What can I do?